# Data binding to custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dynamic-usercontrols

So, I have made my own subclass of UserControl, called ChildView (I really can't come up with a decent name), that I want to show inside a container in a window, I have many different kinds of these UserControls and the window must be capable of showing all of them. The UserControls have implemented my subclass like this:

```xml
<src:ChildView x:Class="(namespace).LoginView" [...]>
```

```cs
public partial class LoginView : ChildView
```

And I have tried to add it to my window like so:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ViewHolder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <src:ChildView DataContext="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
private ChildView _currentView;
public ChildView CurrentView 
{
    get { return _currentView; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentView == value)
            return;

        _currentView = value;
        smLog.Trace("View set to {0}", value.GetType().Name);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. Nothing is shown in my container when I set CurrentView. There are no error messages in the output that would indicate a problem with the binding. Other data bindings in the window works. I can use my ChildViews by specifying their classes directly in the XAML, i.e:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ViewHolder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <src:LoginView />
</Grid>
```

I've read some about dependency properties but I don't think I need one here? I did try to implement one anyway but it didn't seem to help, though I probably made some mistake, I couldn't quite wrap my head around it...

So I guess my question is; do I need a dependency property? If so, how do I implement it in this case? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: try `snoop`. it's wpf utility and very useful to check is your control exists in grid and what exactly problems you have here

Comment: According to Snoop my ViewHolder contains "[007] ChildView 2", and if I check its properties the DataContext is highlighted in green and says "[(namespace).LoginView] {Path=CurrentView}". IsInitialized, IsLoaded, IsVisible, IsEnabled are all true... Height and Width have reasonable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Child's DataContext won't matter, you're trying to change **the control itself**, not the data it's bound to. What you need to do is add a placeholder control that would contain the actual view. WPF has such a thing built in, take a look at [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx).

Change your grid so it'll containt a ContentControl instead of ChildView, and bind the view to the control's Content property

```
<Grid>
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Grid>
```